# Generate bitcoin address from derivation scheme

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitcoin

I have a derivation scheme starting with tpub... for testnet and I want to be able to generate bitcoin addresses from derivation scheme. Also I want a method be applicable to mainnet, is any library available that could help me in this task. And code example how to do it what be great. I was thinking bitcore-lib would help, but didn't found anything useful for my task. But any solution would be fine. All useful information I found was a bunch of bips, but I doubt that I need to do that from scratch, and want to avoid it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a time to publish a full answer now:

```
var runningNetwork = bjs.networks.testnet
const bip32 = require('bip32')
const bjs = require('bitcoinjs-lib')
let { address } = bjs.payments.p2wpkh({pubkey: bip32.fromBase58(dvScheme,runningNetwork).derive(0).derive(1).publicKey,})

console.log(`${address}`)
```